# JBoss Netty : Support for SNI (Server Name Indication)

Tags: ssl, netty, sni

Does the SSL implementation in JBoss Netty support Server Name Indication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more or less the same answer as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11574216/372643): [Java 7 supports SNI, but only from the client side](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html).